# DCPCrypt - Lazarus

Tags: delphi, lazarus, криптография

Я дико извиняюсь, но не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться с [DCPCrypt](http://wiki.freepascal.org/DCPcrypt)?

Не могу никак понять, каким образом нужно обращаться с компонентом. Т.е. как прописать ключ, шифровать и расшифровывать. Более 2 часов ломаю голову, не могу понять.

Вроде как прописывать ключ надо через `.Init`, но получается полная дичь. Например, зашифровал и расшифровал строку, итоговые данные получились разные. Далее сравнивал мою зашифрованную строку с тем, что получил на разных сайтах. Строки различаются.

Пробовал так же сделать через этот [код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188045/how-to-aes-128-encrypt-a-string-using-a-password-in-delphi-and-decrypt-in-c) без использования компонента выше. Получаю ошибку `identifier not found "Encoder.EncodeBytes"`. Далее пытался вместо этих двух процедур, где возникала ошибка, вставить другие процедуры и функции. Один раз получилось, но радости это мало принесло: при шифровании строки `123` я получал шифр, но расшифровав, у меня получилась строка `1`. Т.е. шифровался только первый символ из строки.

Да, документацию читал к компоненту, не понял ни слова.

Comment: http://is.muni.cz/th/51468/fi_b/priloha/DCPcrypt/Docs/Ciphers.html#EncryptString - вот такие примеры пробовали? там и шифровка и дешифровка и строки и файла

Comment: @Tunker, да. [Результат](http://prntscr.com/btcfgl). Код копировал один в один с сайта.

Comment: Насколько я помню это кривое поделие, примеры использования там есть. А то что у вас получается не то, что на сайтах - следствие местами некорректной реализации алгоритмов в самом DCPCrypt.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не могли бы вы помочь? Хотя бы понять, как исправить можно ошибку в [этом коде](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188045/how-to-aes-128-encrypt-a-string-using-a-password-in-delphi-and-decrypt-in-c)? Использовал другие encoder'ы и decoder'ы, получал либо кашу, либо (всего лишь один раз) "шифровался только первый символ из строки".

Comment: `зашифровал и расшифровал строку, итоговые данные получились разные.` Потому что состояние компонента меняется после каждой итерации шифрования/дешифровки. Получается, что дешифровка уже идет с измененным вектором. Попробуйте создать 2 экземпляра класса, один пусть шифрует, другой - расшифровывает. SIGSEGV - это же не Win? DCPCrypt вроде позиционируются как работающие только под Windows.

Comment: "Не то что на сайтах" может получаться из-за разных алгоритмов генерации ключа из пароля.

Comment: @kami, огромное спасибо! Все получилось идеально! Напишите ответ, я помечу как правильный. И нет, у меня Win7, без понятия, почему вылезала данная ошибка, это уже и не важно =) Кстати говоря, можно 2 раза прописывать ключ `DCP_rijndael1.Init`. Строку шифрует, изменяется вектор. Далее сохраняем шифр и снова прописываем ту же самую строку с ключем, ничего не меняя, и дешифруем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Современные алгоритмы шифрования основаны на изменении внутреннего состояния после каждой итерации шифрования/дешифровки данных. Поэтому, попытавшись дважды зашифровать (к примеру) одну и ту же строку, вы получите разный результат на выходе.

Соответственно, для правильной дешифровки данных исходное состояние объекта-дешифровщика должно соответствовать исходному состоянию объекта, реализовывавшего шифрование.

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом `Reset`, имеющемся в каждом из BlockCipher-ов в DCPCrypt:

> Stream ciphers (and block ciphers in chaining modes) generally store
>   chaining information that is dependant on the information already
>   encrypted. Consequently **decrypting a block of information immediately
>   after encrypting it won't result in the original information** because
>   when you called the decrypt procedure the chaining information was
>   different from when you called the encrypt procedure. Hence use `Reset`
>   to restore the chaining information to it's original state.

Обратите внимание, что использование `Reset` (или пере-инициализации объекта через Init) "на каждый чих" значительно снижает стойкость шифрования.

Наиболее правильным, на мой взгляд, было бы создание двух объектов, один из которых - шифрует, другой - расшифровывает данные. В этом случае правильность расшифровки будет гарантирована, если на вход дешифратора данные будут попадать в той же последовательности, в которой они зашифровывались.

Comment: Не могли бы вы еще помочь с [этой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545461/lazarus-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B5) темой?