# Lazarus - кодировка в консольке

Tags: delphi, кодировка, lazarus

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять как работать с кодировками, точнее как мне быть с ними.

Подробнее...
Есть 2 программы: 1 консольное приложение, вторая простая программа. Программой создаю файл, шифрую текст и записываю его в файл. Через консоль я открываю данный файл, дешифрую текст и вывожу на экран.

Проблема заключается в том, что этот текст выводится в другой кодировке. Использовав ["декодер"](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/advanced/), я получил нужный мне результат. Оказывается, что в консоль из файла выводится текст в кодировке CP866, когда сам файл, откуда был взят текст, в UTF-8 (без BOM) кодировке.

Я перепробовал различные варианты изменении кодировки. От простого UTF8ToConsole (после последнего релиза кириллица не выводится в консоль при использовании данной функции, лично я изменил кодировку юнита как раз на CP866, иначе никак вывести в консоль русские символы не могу) до копипаста нескольких функций, которые изменяют кодировку CP866 → CP1251 → UTF-8, и так далее. Что бы я не делал, ничего не выходит. Каким образом можно это все исправить?

P.S. я уже пытался изменить кодировку текста при записи в файл. По-моему не там надо копать, т.к. до записи текст шифруется.

[Файлик](http://u0188536.plsk.regruhosting.ru//debug-1468686630.zip)

**UPD1**

`readln(p);
  assignfile(f,p);
  reset(f);
  while not EOF(f) do
  begin
    Readln(f,s);
    writeln(AES.DecryptString(s));
    writeln(s);
  end;`

После всех попыток решил оставить так, как есть сейчас. Кодировка юнита CP866.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код чтения из файла и вывода информации в консоль. Возможно, вы не там используете перекодировку.

Comment: @kami, готово. Могу предоставить ссылки, откуда я брал и тестировал функции перекодировки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure Writeln2(const S: string);
  var
  s2: string;
  begin
  SetLength(s2, Length(S));
  CharToOem(PChar(S), PChar(s2));
  Writeln(s2);
end;
```

Зачем-то сдуру не стал пробовать данную функцию. Проблема решилась использованием этой и `UTF8ToAnsi` функций.

Т.е. получилось следующее: `writeln2(UTF8ToAnsi(AES.DecryptString(s)));`.

Отдельное спасибо пользователю [kami](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192901/kami) за потраченное на меня время и решение проблемы в [прошлом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545277/dcpcrypt-lazarus?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @kami, так у меня и сейчас файл в UTF8. Ну по крайней мере Notepad++ так пишет. Не уж то ли надо тогда использовать [этот код](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501758/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-utf-8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-lazarus?rq=1)?

Comment: Моя ошибка - не посмотрел, что Ваш код как раз используется не для записи в файл, а для вывода в консоль. Удаляю предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @kami, если же надо будет импортировать и экспортировать какие-либо данные, тогда уже пользоваться `TFileStream`?

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);` не проще?